# Is it possible to add a 1px border around a transparent vector / svg?

Tags: css, svg, vector

I have the following sample vector:
https://jsfiddle.net/fuho74vp/1/

Here's the sample code:

```
<div style="background-color: red;">
  <svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve" style="border: 1px solid green;">
  <path d="M25,48c12.683,0,23-10.317,23-23S37.683,2,25,2S2,12.317,2,25S12.317,48,25,48z M23,17h10v10l-4.293-4.293l-12,12
    l-1.414-1.414l12-12L23,17z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Is it possible, using CSS, to apply a 1px solid green border round the vector, and have it "hug" the vector? I want the green border to go around all the visible portions of the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it using the `vector-effect` attribute. Here's an example of a heart:

```
<svg height="1124pt" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 1286 1124" width="1286pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="m3350 11234c-25-2-103-9-175-15-446-37-929-171-1316-364-1073-537-1732-1546-1849-2830-13-142-13-472 0-650 95-1295 727-2420 2057-3666 448-420 852-765 1633-1399 481-390 1057-882 1350-1154 187-174 586-577 733-741 216-242 271-294 354-338 90-47 175-67 290-67 111 0 177 13 262 51 95 43 150 90 270 229 269 313 652 694 1084 1078 318 282 496 433 1222 1032 503 415 745 618 953 798 631 546 1130 1044 1485 1484 737 914 1106 1811 1153 2803 7 169-10 514-37 724-153 1205-828 2169-1865 2668-366 176-775 289-1227 339-212 24-638 25-800 1-547-78-1089-309-1625-691-273-195-490-378-761-645l-114-112-146 143c-769 753-1559 1193-2341 1304-100 14-494 26-590 18z" transform="matrix(.1 0 0 -.1 0 1124)" fill="transparent" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="0" />
    <path d="m3350 11234c-25-2-103-9-175-15-446-37-929-171-1316-364-1073-537-1732-1546-1849-2830-13-142-13-472 0-650 95-1295 727-2420 2057-3666 448-420 852-765 1633-1399 481-390 1057-882 1350-1154 187-174 586-577 733-741 216-242 271-294 354-338 90-47 175-67 290-67 111 0 177 13 262 51 95 43 150 90 270 229 269 313 652 694 1084 1078 318 282 496 433 1222 1032 503 415 745 618 953 798 631 546 1130 1044 1485 1484 737 914 1106 1811 1153 2803 7 169-10 514-37 724-153 1205-828 2169-1865 2668-366 176-775 289-1227 339-212 24-638 25-800 1-547-78-1089-309-1625-691-273-195-490-378-761-645l-114-112-146 143c-769 753-1559 1193-2341 1304-100 14-494 26-590 18z" transform="matrix(.1 0 0 -.1 0 1124)" fill="transparent" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="4,4" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I add 1px green border around a transparent vector SVG.

Please try the code below.

```
<div style="background-color: red;">
  <svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve" style="border: 1px solid green;">
  <path stroke="green" stroke-width="0.3" d="M25,48c12.683,0,23-10.317,23-23S37.683,2,25,2S2,12.317,2,25S12.317,48,25,48z M23,17h10v10l-4.293-4.293l-12,12
    l-1.414-1.414l12-12L23,17z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can add the border to the parent div and make div as a circle, like:

```html
<div style="background-color: red; border: 10px solid green; border-radius: 1000px">
  <svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve" >
  <path d="M25,48c12.683,0,23-10.317,23-23S37.683,2,25,2S2,12.317,2,25S12.317,48,25,48z M23,17h10v10l-4.293-4.293l-12,12
    l-1.414-1.414l12-12L23,17z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

(of course 1px)

But maybe the best would be to draw the border directly in the svg...

Comment: Yes I think so.